# Matlab if statement logic

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I have to write code for a robot to pick up bolts either of type 1 or type 2 and then put them into either holes that correspond to type one or type 2.

The problem i'm having is the data in the excel spreadsheet is setup in a way where I can't change the order of it. For example, the hole type vector will have 1 1 1 2 2 2, but the bolt type vector will be 1 2 1 2 1 2. The problem is if the hole type is 1 and the bolt type is 2, the program ends and won't place the bolt in the hole. I need help writing it so even if the bolt type is 1 and the hole type is 2, it will still place it in hole 1.

```
clc
clear variables
close all

Data=xlsread('Sample_Data'); %read in data from excel spread sheet
[n_rows,n_cols]=size(Data); %obtains the number of rows and columns from data

file_no=initialize('Robot_Project.txt'); 

x_hole=Data(1:6,1); % creates vector for hole x_coordinates
y_hole=Data(1:6,2); % creates vector for hole y_coordinates
bolt_type=Data(7:12,3); % creates vector seperating bolts into type 1 or 2
hole_type=Data(1:6,3); % creates vector seperating holes into type 1 or 2



for i=1:n_rows/2
    if bolt_type(i) == 1 && hole_type(i) == 1;
        pickup(file_no) % pickup function
        moveto(file_no,x_hole(i),y_hole(i)) %moves 
        putdown(file_no) % putdown function
    elseif bolt_type(i) == 2 && hole_type(i) == 1;
        pickup(file_no)
        moveto(file_no,x_hole(i),y_hole(i))
        putdown(file_no)
    end
end
```

Comment: Surely this is just another extension to your `if` statement, much like your `elseif bolt_type(i) == 2 && hole_type(i) == 1`? That is, add extra lines for the cases of bolt 1 with type 2, and bolt 2 with type 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1:number_of_bolts
    pickup;

    first_fitting_hole = find(hole_type == bolt_type(i),1); 
    % this line finds the first hole which matches the type of the bolt just picked up

    moveto(x_hole(first_fitting_hole),y_hole(first_fitting_hole));
    putdown;

    hole_type(first_fitting_hole)=0; 
    % set type of that particular hole to 0 (i.e. filled hole)

end
```